# .export returns an error "Query could not be parsed" when trying to execute it in the browser query textbox

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-explorer

I'm new to Azure and I'm having troubles. Please help me. Following the article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/data-export/export-data-to-sql), I cannot execute the  **.export** query in the browser. It throws **Query could not be parsed at '.' on line [1,0]**

```
 .export async to sql ['test-continuous-export.database.windows.net.myFirstTable']
    h@"Server=myConnectionstring" with (createifnotexists="true", primarykey="Id")
    <| print Message = "Hello World!", Timestamp = now(), Id=12345678
```

I expect the simple printed message to be logged into the database, but it throws an error on the first char.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and improve your question.

Comment: you may want to include a client request ID with your error. that said, the error message suggests a syntactic error, and i suspect you're running a text which is different than the one you've pasted in your original message, as it does not reproduce for me

Comment: Hi @YoniL, here it is the support id: 4e0f4b18-fbbf-4d9b-8571-38d284409229. This is the exact query that I'm trying to execute in the query in Log Analytics workspace -the text box with the blue "RUN" button above. That's the place where I'm executing all the normal queries. Maybe I should execute them somewhere else, because the keyword .export is not blue?

Comment: that clarifies it - the command you're running is command that runs against a Kusto/Azure Data Explorer cluster. not against a LogAnalytics workspace. these are 2 different services, and even though the query language for both is similar-or-identical, management/control commands are significantly different

Comment: @Yoni Sorry this is old, but is there anyway to export data from LogAnalytics or AppInsight workspace using same or similar query asked in above question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you're running is command that runs against a Kusto/Azure Data Explorer cluster, not against a LogAnalytics workspace. These are two different services, and even though the query language for both is similar-or-identical, management/control commands are significantly different.